# Split Power BI Column Based on Delimiter /n

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have values in my column that are similar to below:

```
Requestor
Manual Requisition
Testing
```

I tried Split Column by Delimiter = /n but nothing actually happened... How would I split this single cell so that the 3 lines end up being their own column?

Answer (score 0):

In the Power Query language M, a line feed is written `#(lf)` and a carriage return is `#(cr)`. So your code might look something like this:

```
Table.SplitColumn(
    #"Previous Step", "ColumnName",
    Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv)
)
```

See [here](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/10/16/split-by-line-breaks/) for more detail.